# Washed the cat with human shampoo, Help!

Tags: cats, grooming

This is my first persian pet and I made a horrible mistake by washing the cat with human shampoo. After that we have never seen healthy coat and the cat has continuous hair loss. I came to know that this is something related to pH dont know exactly what. Will the pH reaction be reversed if I wash the cat with a cat shampoo ? It has been 3 months that the kitten has poor coat and so small hair.

Comment: the first thing to do is take your cat to the vet for an examination and when this is done update your question.it is not likely the shampoo is still affecting your cat.

Comment: My male cat is 9month old , there is no female cat in our house, it is not neutered yet, does no neutering at this age causes hairfall?

Comment: It shouldn't. Cat to vet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to wash your cat at all unless it has come in contact with something that sticks to the fur.

After 3 months the shampoo is long gone, so it must be something else wrong with the fur/skin of your cat. The trouble with human types of shampoo is, they are made to remove types of fat on our skin, and this will dry out your cat's skin and damage it.

A similar question to this one has been asked before on this site so you can find more information about this here: [Can I bathe my cat with shampoo?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5805/can-i-bathe-my-cat-with-shampoo).

it can be a number of things like allergy-fleas-lice or even just dry skin. So you need to let your vet examine your cat to find the reason for the problem.

There are a couple of things you might try. Get a cat brush and brush the cat twice a week and take your time brush slowly and remove the old hair as you go.

Brushing will stimulate the blood flow in the skin and make any damages heal faster.

You can also start giving your cat fish oil (NOT COD LIVER OIL). You can get fish oil from pet shops, vets or online. Follow the recommended dosage.

fish oil can have a positive effect on your cat's skin and fur and general health by giving your cat omega-3 and other essential oils and some nutrients.

Comment: Just to mention it: you can just rinse your cat off with plain water with no soap or shampoo or just a damp washcloth. shampoos are surfactants whose function is to remove oils/fats. If your cat is covered with mud or dirt or someone spilled orange juice on your cat, soap is not needed to clean your cat as substances like these are not oils. I mention this since there is growing criticism of the overuse of soap by dermatologists. Also In the wild cats get wet from rain or swimming from time to time, so It may be healthy to simulate this at home by giving them a quick rinse a few times a year.

Comment: My male cat is 9month old , there is no female cat in our house, it is not neutered yet, does no neutering at this age causes hairfall?

Comment: neutering do not change the growth of a cats fur but environmental factors can change the fur.the lenght of daylight will make your cat shed more fur in spring and and again when the days are getting shorter to prepare your cat for winter even if it is an indoor only cat.

Answer (score 0):

I love cats and I lived with cats in all my life.
Cat doesn’t need a bath. Cat’s saliva has own natural sanitation to groom themselves that’s why cat never smells bad compared to dogs. Dog must be washed every month.

However, if cat has very dirty spots from street or if a vet recommends cat to be washed, then yes but it’s gonna be once a lifetime normally.
If your cat plays in the kitchen and then human food or sauce on cats, then that’s the time you need to wash him with cat shampoo.

Human shampoo is very strong and it can’t be used for cats or dogs.
Think cats and dogs are infants. They are babies.

We don’t wash infants with human adult shampoo because it’s strong.